# Xcode + PhoneGap + Making photo = no camera available

Tags: xcode, cordova

Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4
PhoneGap 1.2

I'm building my application with **Ipad 6.0 Simulator**.

```
var pictureSource,
  destinationType;

function onDeviceReady() {
  pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
  destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;

  if (noConnection()) alert("No internet connection. Working in offline mode.");

  deviceId = device.uuid;

  initDb();
  initFileSystem();
}

 $("#take-photo").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoUriSuccess,
      onPhotoFail,
      {quality: 85, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI}
    );
    return false;
  });
```

Looks like everything is right But I get an error **'no camera available'**.
Maybe it's because of I'm running my application wuth **Ipad 6.0 Simulator**.

I have **Ipad 6.0 Simulator** and **iOS Device** are available for my application.
When I choose **iOS Device** and run I get an error **'no provisioned iOS devices are available with compatible iOS version...'**

**How can I make my camera to be available?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your suspicion is well-founded. The simulator doesn't provide a camera.

Comment: Marcelo, thanks for help. I edited th question. How can fit my problem?

Comment: @LeshaPipiev: Have you registered as an Apple developer? You can't deploy to iOS devices until you do.

Comment: Marcelo, I guess I did. I have Apple Id and I can use Apple store. Maybe my problem is I don't understand what iOS device means. Actually I want to deploy my xcode application on something like 'local host' or 'local Mac'.

Comment: @LeshaPipiev: An Apple ID isn't enough. You need to enrol in the [developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/).